# Error: 'GL/glfw3.h: No such file or directory' when compiling C++ programs using OpenGL on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

I receive the error message

```
GL/glfw3.h: No such file or directory
```

when I try to compile the example program given in the tutorial [here](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-1-opening-a-window/), section 'Opening a window'. I have installed all the libraries they referred to in the 'Building on Linux' section. (My distribution is Ubuntu 16.04.)

I have also successfully run

```
apt-get install libglfw-dev
```

as I found suggested somewhere as an answer to this issue.

I think the glfw3 library has possibly been installed in a place that the compiler does not know how to automatically access.

How do I find out if this is the case, where should I put it so it can be accessed (`/usr/share`?), and what exactly do I put there? I've copied a file called `libglfw3.a` that I found in `/usr/local/lib` to `/usr/share`, but the error reoccurred.

I've tried compiling it using
`g++ first.c -o first`
and
`g++ first.c -lglut -lGL -lGLEW -lglfw -o first`. That error message alone occurred both times (which makes me think the other libraries don't even need to be linked?)

I'm a pretty new user. The solution is probably obvious.

Comment: Command `dpkg -L libglfw-dev` should show you some relevant information. libglfw3-dev might be actually the package you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easy fix (the solution was indeed obvious).

`#include <GL/glfw3.h>` should be `#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>`